# python class array with different data types

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, class

I recently changed my religion from Matlab to Python for my data-analysis. I often need to import a lot of data-files which I used to store in a structure array in Matlab. This way I could both store a lot of different data in a single structure-array where the parameters to which the data belongs will be stored within this structure. I would end up with structures like:

```
data(i).parameterx = a
data(i).parametery = b
data(i).data1 = [3, 5, 7, 8, 423, 2, 56, 6]
data(i).data2 = [4, 2, 5; 4, 6, 2; 5, 1, 3]
```

The length of `data` is the number of data-files I imported. This way I can retrieve all the parameters of each data-set based on the index of `data`.
So I want to do the same in Python. I tried using `class` but it seems that I can't store it in an array.
What I tried was the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Import modules
import numpy                as np
import fnmatch
import os

# Set up all elements of the path
class path:
    main, dir = 'root/dir', 'data_dir'
    complete = os.path.join(main,dir)
    ext = 'odt'     # Extension of the file to look for

# Initialize data array and data-class
all_data=[]
class odt_data:
    pass

# Loop through all files in path.complete and find all ODT-files
for (root, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path.complete):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.'+path.ext):
        # Only ODT-files
        # Extract parameters from filename
        parameters = filename.split('__')
        odt_data.parameterx = parameters[0]; odt_data.parametery = parameters[2]

        # Import data from file and assign to correct attribute of 'odt_data'
        file=os.path.join(root, filename)
        data=np.loadtxt(file)
        odt_data.data1 = data[:,0]; odt_data.data2 = data[:,1]

        # Append new data to array of all data
        all_data.append(odt_data)
```

The problem here is that is doesn't really save the data in `odt_data` but rather the reference to it. Hence when I do `print(all_data)` the result is:

```
[<class '__main__.odt_data'>, <class '__main__.odt_data'>, <class '__main__.odt_data'>]
```

And therefore only the last imported data is stored: `all_data[0]` is exactly the same as `all_data[1]` and so on. Hence, I'm not able to access the data of the first or second imported file, only that of the last one. So when I call `all_data[1].parameterx` I get the `parameterx` value of the last imported file, not the second!
**NOTE: I don't care about how it prints, I only care about accessing all the imported data**

Anybody knows a way to store the actual data in class `odt_data` in an array (or possibly use something else than a `class`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to initialize the class in the loop.

However, this isn't how you would store such data in Python.  You don't benefit from using a class here (in either case).  Python actually has structured arrays, but it is overkill in this situation.  The simplest solution would be to use a list of dicts:

```
# Import modules
import numpy as np
import os

main = 'root/dir'
dir = 'data_dir'
complete = os.path.join(main,dir)
ext = '.odt'     # Extension of the file to look for

# Initialize data array
all_data = []

for root, _, filenames in os.walk(path.complete):
    for filename in filenames:
        if os.path.splitext(filename)[-1] != ext:
            continue

        odt_data = {}
        # Only ODT-files
        # Extract parameters from filename
        odt_data['parameterx'], odt_data['parametery'] = filename.split('__')

        # Import data from file and assign to correct attribute of 'odt_data'
        fname = os.path.join(root, filename)
        data = np.loadtxt(fname)
        odt_data['data1'] = data[:,0]
        odt_data['data2'] = data[:,1]

        # Append new data to array of all data
        all_data.append(odt_data)
```

Comment: List of dicts is indeed the way to go here. I have one additional question about your script: what does the `pass` in your `if`-statement do? Because how I interpret `pass` it means it just goes out of the if-statement and the part after that is executed whether the condition is true or not.

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be `continue`, not `pass`.  I fixed it.